# Android Intent map data being overwritten

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

I am adding 4 Extras to an Intent and for some reason, 1 slot in the map of the Intent gets overwritten every time. It is always the same slot unless I change what order my Extras are added, then the slot which gets overwritten changes. Here are pictures:
[Okay so far...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ohwj.png)

Step forward...
[Step forward and my int is gone?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRz3P.png)
Adding the last Extra works fine.
[Final extra looks good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViUZP.png)

I checked my variables and all of the data exists correctly in the mTeamMemberFrag. Using breakpoints, I can see that the first and second Extras are added no problem, then the third one overwrites the first one, then the fourth one adds no problem. I can see that I'm not mapping them to the same key. I have searched on Stack Overflow and read through the Android documentation for Intents and Intent Filters. I have tried changing the values that get added to hardcoded values, I have tried changing the order in which the Extras are added, and I double-checked the static final variables in MainActivity.

Well, while double-checking the variables in Main as I wrote this I found what was causing my error: both USERNAMEKEY and USERPOSITIONKEY were assigned "com.zin.username" in the MainActivity, so depending on which one I added first to the Intent, one was overwriting the other.

I would love to know why that was happening. Thanks for your time!

Here's my code where I load the Intent:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    mTeamMemberFrag.updateUserID();
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.USERNAMEKEY, mTeamMemberFrag.getUserName());
    resultIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.USERIDKEY, mTeamMemberFrag.getUserID());
    resultIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.USERROLEKEY, mTeamMemberFrag.getSpinner().getSelectedItem().toString());
    resultIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.USERPOSITIONKEY, mMemberPosition);

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Team updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And in Main where the problem actually was:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String USERIDKEY = "com.zin.userid";
    public static final String USERPOSITIONKEY = "com.zin.username";
    public static final String USERNAMEKEY = "com.zin.username";
    public static final String USERROLEKEY = "com.zin.userrole";
```

Comment: Have you tried with clean and rebuilding the project?

Comment: code you provided is not enough. I bet you are changing values somehow

Comment: @Nas Thank you I did try that! It didn't fix it. Now I understand that the value of the static final variable USERPOSITIONKEY is what was causing the problem. It was set = "com.zin.username", which was causing my Intent to map those two values to the same key, overriding whichever was written first with whatever was written second. Changing the value of that static final variable fixed the problem with my Intent map extras.

Comment: @Zaid Mirza Thank you for being willing to help! I wasn't changing the values on purpose, but I was mapping both values to the same key in the HashMap where the Intent stores Extras, causing the first value to be overwritten by the second value. Changing the value of the static final variable in MainActivity (which is what I was using for my key) fixed the problem. Thank you again!